# Help with a simple derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I am trying to solve $\dfrac {6} {\sqrt {x^3+6}}$ 
and so far I made it to $6(x^3+6)^{-\frac 1 2}$ 
then I continued and now I have $(x^3+6)^{- \frac 3 2} * 3x^2$
and I cannot figure out what how to find the constant that should be before the parenthesis.

Comment: you missed your $\frac{-1}{2}$ out front and forgot about the $6$

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site, and thank you for including the work you've already done on this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. I have been trying to learn the chain rule and was wondering what part I wasn't comprehending thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

$\dfrac{d}{dx} \left(\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{x^3+6}}\right) = 6 \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+6}}\right) = 6\cdot -\dfrac{1}{2}\left(x^3+6\right)^{\frac{-3}{2}}\cdot 3x^2 = -9x^2\left(x^3+6\right)^{\frac{-3}{2}}$ via chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{6}{\sqrt{x^3+6}})= 6\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+6}})\\
\implies 6\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+6}})=6\frac{d}{d(x^2+6)}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+6}})\frac{d}{dx}(x^3+6)=\frac{-3}{(x^3+6)^{3/2}}\cdot 3x^2=-9\frac{x^2}{(x^3+6)^{3/2}}$$